# Display Dropdown (bootstrap-ui-datetime-picker) out of md-dialog

Tags: css, angularjs, angular-material

I am using `md-dialog` to display a form.

Form contains `md-input-container` which displays `input` tags and `select` tags.
The last container shows up `https://github.com/Gillardo/bootstrap-ui-datetime-picker`

```
<md-input-container class="md-block" flex-gt-sm>
    <label>Time</label>
    <p class="input-group">
        <input type="text" class="form-control" datetime-picker="MM/dd/yyyy HH:mm" ng-model="scheduledJob.date" is-open="scheduledJob.open"/>
        <span class="input-group-btn">
              <button type="button" class="btn btn-default" ng-click="openCalendar($event, scheduledJob)">
                  <i class="fa fa-calendar"></i></button>
          </span>
    </p>
</md-input-container>
```

But whenever this gets clicked, the `md-dialog` starts showing a scroll bar like this:

[image]

How can make this particular dropdown fall outside of `md-dialog`, Here is a quick [CodePen](https://codepen.io/singhnk/pen/dyYvaQy?editors=1010) of the issue I am facing.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Define datepicker option `datepicker-append-to-body="true"` in your `input` element.

```
<input type="text" class="form-control" datetime-picker="MM/dd/yyyy HH:mm" 
   datepicker-append-to-body="true" ng-model="scheduledJob.date" 
   is-open="scheduledJob.open"/>
```

From [angular-ui/bootstrap](https://github.com/angular-ui/bootstrap/tree/master/src/datepickerPopup) readme:

> `datepicker-append-to-body` (Default: false, Config: appendToBody) - Append the datepicker popup element to body, rather than inserting after datepicker-popup.

Comment: I am facing a follow up question on the same codepen, shall I raise another question or shall I ask here itself.

Comment: Please post a new question.

Comment: Ok, I posted a new one: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61442029/getting-error-compilectreq-missing-required-controller-even-after-defining-c